# Why is the data update method not working?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, json-server

I want to update the information about the post in the `GalleryService` using the `update` method. When I click on the `Edit` button I go to the address of the selected post, its data are in the input fields. After I change something in the fields and click on the `Update Post` button to change the post, my form will close, but no changes will occur. There are also no errors, tell me what my problem is and help solve it.

**Button `Edit` in the component `GalleryItemComponent`:**

```html
<a class="btn btn-success ed"  [routerLink] = "['/galleryEdit', pic.id]"  (click)="editPost(pic)">Edit</a>
```

**Form in `GalleryEditComponent`:**

```html
    <form [formGroup]="angFormEd" novalidate>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="titleEd"  #titleEd
               [(ngModel)]="post.title"/>

        <input type="url" class="form-control" formControlName="urlEd" #urlEd pattern="https?://.+"
               title="Include http://" [(ngModel)]="post.url"/>
 
        <button (click)="updatePost(titleEd.value, urlEd.value)"  
                [disabled]=" angFormEd.invalid">
                btn btn-primary">Update Post</button>     
    </form>
```

**`GalleryEditComponent.ts`:**

```js
export class GalleryEditComponent implements OnInit {
    post: Picture;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
                private route: ActivatedRoute, private galleryService: GalleryService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.editPost();
    }

    editPost(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.galleryService.edit(params['id']).subscribe(res => {
                this.post = res;
            })
        })
    }

    updatePost(title: string, url: string): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.galleryService.update(title, url, params['id']);
        });
    }
}
```

** `GalleryService.ts`:**

```js
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

export class GalleryService {
    galleryUrl: string = 'http://localhost:5555/posts';
    Mycollection: Picture[] = myCollection;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getPictures(): Observable<Picture[]> {
        return this.http.get<Picture[]>(`${this.galleryUrl}`);
    }

    edit(id:number): Observable<Picture> {
        return this.http.get<Picture>(`${this.galleryUrl}/${id}`);
    }

    update(title: string, url: string, id: number): Observable<Picture> {
        const postEdObj = {
          title,
            url
        };
        return this.http.put<Picture>(`${this.galleryUrl}/${id}`, postEdObj, httpOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no changes will occur"? Is the view not updated in the browser but the post is updated on the server or no change at all? Also, consider posting your code in stackblitz. Makes it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: the post does not change not in the interface not on the server

Comment: have you checked the database if it is changing over there but not reflecting here in the form as you haven't subscribed to the to the data in update function

Comment: data does not change in the database

Comment: post `console.log(postEdObj)`

Comment: the object changes in the service, changes are visible in the console but it does not change in the database

Comment: show the console.log value

Comment: its console.log(`${this.galleryUrl}/${id}`); - http://localhost:5555/posts/1
its  console.log(postEdObj);  after changes: {title: "123", url: "https://placekitten.com/200/198"}

Comment: I send the data correct, but for some reason they do not change in the database

Comment: the show your backend code

Comment: i use json-server for backend

Comment: then maybe your backend has some issue, query is not running properly, as i can see rest of the code is fine.

Comment: ok,  thx,  i will search  a problem